# Java - dynamically generate Radio Buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, radio-button

Can someone give me some tips on how to dynamically generate nested radio buttons ? I never worked with radio buttons in JAVA, so before I start maybe I'll find some useful tips around here. I read the information from a database and using that I want to create some radio buttons, with drop down as well.

Something like this:

[image]

When I press My Savings Account a new drop down panel will appear with the set of the products that account has. Also I want my response for these radio buttons choice to be stored.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: ArrayLists can store dynamic number of elements

Comment: use loops to generate number of loops. Then hide the sub divided radio options. Enable them to visible, only when major button is selected.

Comment: For nesting properly use a JTree and render the nodes to radio buttons. It should even work with ButtonGroup to control for only one button selected.

Comment: Ye ... I'll make use of ButtonGroup. I have a framework of drop down panels and I'll stick to it as well. I guess I'm on the right path till now :).

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you could use nested `JPanel`'s and `EmptyBorder`

Comment: here are a few JTree with JCheckBox as TreeCellRenderer/Editor, but ButtonGroup will be required little bit effort, use JComboBox as TreeCellEditor instead of bunch of code required for JRadioButtons in ButtonGroup as TreeCellRender/Editor, search for code stored only Boolean value,

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend you to use nesting. It is good practice to use UI where components are aligned with each other as possible, and nesting would create vertical alignment for every level of nested components. Also in combination with radio buttons it requires large area of empty user interface!

Instead of nesting you could place each level of radio buttons under previous level of radio buttons. Selecting radio button in one level would enable and update radio buttons in level under. Something like this, but imagine more radio button groups:

[image: radio button groups]

Also you could replace radio buttons with combo boxes. That would save additional space and make UI even simpler.

If you really want radio button nesting, i would use GridBagLayout. Every radio button would be in one row and filling multiple columns. Every level of radio buttons would start on next column:

[image: Radio buttons with grid]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here Simple Exercise of adding button into the Swing and yes this example uses RadioButton.

Here check it out this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            final JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("Kishan"+i);
            jPanel1.add(button1);
            buttonGroup1.add(button1);

            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.err.println("Action Performed..************");
                    System.out.println("This is action text.."+button1.getText()); 

                }
            });

        }
```